# ionic 4 pass data back from modal which is opened inside another modal to base page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page called `home.component.ts`. On this page, a modal called `address-modal(first modal)` is opened to let users select an address and the selected address is passed back to the home page. Meanwhile, On `address-modal(first modal)`, If the user wants to add another address there is another modal called `add-address-modal(second modal)` is opened on button click.

Now when a user adds another address (the second modal is opened on the first modal) I want to dismiss both modals send a newly added address to `home.apge` without really sending it to `address-modal`.

Currently

1. I am getting data back from `address-modal(first modal)` to home page
2. I am getting data from `add-address-modal(second modal)` to `address-modal(first modal)`

**But I want to get data directly from 2nd modal to base page**

here is my code

home.module.ts // base page

```
import { AddressPage } from '../pages/address/address.page';
import { AddAddressPage } from '../pages/add-address/add-address.page'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   // all imports
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage, AddressPage, AddAddressPage],
  entryComponents :[AddressPage , AddAddressPage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AddressPage } from '../pages/address/address.page';

 constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {}


  async address_modal(){
    // console.log("clicked")
     const modal = await this.modalController.create({
       component: AddressPage,

     });

     modal.onDidDismiss()
     .then((data) => {
       const user = data['data']; // Here's your selected user!
       console.log("from address "  + user)

   });

     return await modal.present();
   }
}
```

home.html

```
  <ion-button (click) = "address_modal()">address</ion-button> // to open first modal
```

address.page.ts // first modal

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AddAddressPage } from '../add-address/add-address.page'

 x:any;

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { 
   this.x =2;
  }

close(){
    this.modalController.dismiss(this.x)
  }


    async add_address(){


      // console.log("clicked")
       const modal = await this.modalController.create({
         component: AddAddressPage,

       });
       modal.onDidDismiss()
       .then((data) => {
         const user = data['data']; // Here's your selected user!
         console.log( "from add-adreess"  + user)

     });

       return await modal.present();
     }
```

address.html

```
<ion-button (click)="close()">close</ion-button> // close modal
<ion-button (click)="add_address()">open</ion-button> // open second modal
```

add-address.page.ts

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

 x:any;
  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {
    this.x =5;
   }


  close(){
    this.modalController.dismiss(this.x)
  }
```

add-address.html

```
  <ion-button (click) ="close()">close</ion-button >
```

Comment: Close your 1st Modal (programmatically) before opening 2nd modal then you can get 2nd modal's data directly to the base page.

Comment: Or pass a parameter when closing second modal, which triggers a dismiss event for the first modal with the passed data.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Closing first modal before opening second one is fine

Comment: I need to lazy load both modals. Here is another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59948237/7628381 hope you can help

Comment: Hello @NajamUsSaqib . I have a small problem. I am closing the first modal before opening second modal, but the second modal's dismiss event is on modal1.ts  page. Thus passed data with dismiss event is also on modal1.ts page but I need to access that data on the base page. How can I do that?

Comment: Then Make a Global Class for data. Save your data to that class and access it on your Base page. Or you can use Ionic Events Library.

Comment: Events are depreciated in ionic4. Can you please elaborate about the first option? some code ?